# Ajax request jquery

Tags: ajax, web-services, web

Need 
Pull PlanId from the Get variable send it to Web Service and I have GetPlanInfo function 
Get the details of the package and display them

```html
var MainServiceURL = 'http://someWebService';
var plan=[];

function planInit()
{
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  url: MainServiceURL + "/GetPlanInfo",
  data: {"ID" : ID ,"countryID" : CountryID},
  success: function(response) {
   plan = response.d;
   main();
  }
 });
}


function main(plan)
{
          
   document.getElementById("costPerMonth").innerHTML = plan.CostPerMonth;
            document.getElementById("firstMonthPrice").innerHTML =   plan.FirstMonthPrice;
            document.getElementById("planName").innerHTML = plan.Name;
            document.getElementById("landline").innerHTML = plan.Landline;
            document.getElementById("mobile").innerHTML = plan.Mobile;  
 
 }
```

Where error?

Answer (score 0):

Within the function **main** you treat a **plan** variable like a known object and you try to access its properties. However, **plan** is only an **argument** for the function main, which you don't pass once you get the response from your request. Look at:

```
success: function(response) {
            plan = response.d;
            main();
        }
```

When you write like this, you call **main** function without passing **plan** argument. It should look like:

```
success: function(response) {
            plan = JSON.parse(response).d;
            main(plan);
        }
```

Because as a response you only get a string - you have to translate it to JSON object using `JSON.parse` function.

Comment: Well, could you please do the simplest possible sort of debugging and just after `function(response) {` add `console.log(response);` or `alert(response);`? Please paste the result here and for sure I can give you more details :) .

Comment: This where I jump after breakpoint
  messagingNatives.BindToGC(responseCallback, function() {
        if (port) {
          privates(port).impl.destroy_();
          port = null;
        }
      }, portId);
      var rv = requestEvent.dispatch(request, sender, responseCallback);
      if (isSendMessage) {
        responseCallbackPreserved =
            rv && rv.results && $Array.indexOf(rv.results, true) > -1;
        if (!responseCallbackPreserved && port) 
          privates(port).impl.destroy_();
          port = null;
        }
      }
    }

Comment: `success: function(response) { console.log(response); }` Please just give me the output from your console :) .

Comment: measureIt.js:120 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Comment: Hm, please paste the full console log here, as there is no "create" property in the code you have shown so far in your question.